# Connect/disconnect from VPN from the command line

Tags: command-line, network-manager, vpn, pptp, vpnc

I have two VPNs setup on my Ubuntu machine, one using vpnc and one using PPTP. These were both setup using the GNOME network manager interface and work great. However on occasion I need to access this machine remotely - is there a way to connect or disconnect to these VPNs from the command line?

Comment: Does the vpnc command detailed [here](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-connect-to-a-cisco-vpn-using-vpnc) not work for you? Also, there are instructions for configuring and connecting to PPTP [here.](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-configure-pptp-vpn-in-ubuntu-intrepid-and-jaunty.html) Do they not work?

Answer (score 311, accepted):

If you want to interact with [NetworkManager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager) from the command line, you can use the "nmcli" command.

- List all NM connections: `nmcli con`
- Start connection (Wi-Fi, VPN, etc.): `nmcli con up id ConnectionName`
- Down connection: `nmcli con down id ConnectionName`

More `nmcli` subcommands in the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=NetworkManager.conf.5&titles=404)).

---

Also note that regular users usually don't have permission to control networking. Using the commands above with `sudo` should work for most connections, but VPN specifically might fail with *"Error: Connection activation failed: no valid VPN secrets."*

If that happens to you, it's likely that the VPN password is stored in your user's gnome-keyring, which makes it inaccessible to the root user. [This comment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=710552#c3) explains why.

To fix this, edit **/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ConnectionName** and under `[vpn]`, change the [password flags](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/migrating-to-09/secrets-flags.html) line to:

```
password-flags=0
```

If there is a line starting with `Xauth password-flags`, change it instead.

Then add the following below the `[vpn]` block:

```
[vpn-secrets]
password=YourPassword
```

If in the previous step you changed the line `Xauth password-flags`, add `Xauth password=...` instead.

Now restart network manager by:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Then starting the VPN connection with `sudo nmcli con up id ConnectionName` should work without problems.

Comment: I wish there was a general disconnect command that would disconnect any VPN without having to specify its id. That would probably make [this feature](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-vpnc/+bug/1215262) (I want) easier to implement.

Comment: If you're using ipsec (e.g. vpnc), you may also need to add "IPSec secret-flags=0" and "IPSec secret=<grouppw>" in their respective places

Comment: This still didn't fix me :(  I get a message "Error: Connection activation failed: unknown reason."

Comment: I take that back... after the 3rd time I ran the command it worked. 1st time is failed quickly.  2nd time failed slowly.  Third time worked!

Comment: Note that `id` is a literal. For example, to bring up connection `workvpn` you would type `nmcli con up id workvpn`

Comment: Clear text PWs?? Really?? Does anyone have a SECURE solution?

Comment: @ihashacks solution works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 however I've had to do:
    
     sudo service network-manager restart

after file modification - please add this to your solution as final step

Comment: Fyi: "nmcli c" has the same output.

Thanx for posting this.

Comment: This works, but after disconnecting, the VPN's DNS entry still is at the top of /etc/resolvd.conf causing DNS resolution hangs. Syslog complains with things like `dns-sd-resolved[0xblah]: Failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 24 not known`

Comment: On the last Ubuntu 22.04 and maybe later, you don't need change anything, you only need add the `--ask` parameter like this: `nmcli con up id VPNNAME --ask`

Answer (score 5):

[ihashacks's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/57409/349837) with [Matt's comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57339/connect-disconnect-from-vpn-from-the-command-line#comment746445_57409) worked for me... almost.  Had to tweak one line.

My password-flag line actually read: "`Xauth password-flag`". The accepted answer wouldn't work for me until I changed to the following

```
[vpn]
...
Xauth password-flag=0
IPSec secret-flags=0

[vpn-secrets]
Xauth password=<my pw> ## This is the one I changed.
IPSec secret=<group pw>
```

Not sure why my VPN connections have "`Xauth`" before every mention of password.

Comment: This is for some types of VPN, for example, the Cisco one; very helpful for these cases! There is a mistake, though: the correct case of one key is `IPSec secret` - otherwise, it's not recognized by NM.