# How To Initiate VPN From Terminal

Tags: command-line, vpn, pptp

Under "System" > "Preferences" > "Network Connections" I can create PPTP VPNs. This works when I am at a GUI, I can click the network connections icon in the top right, and select a VPN from the list and connect to it.

Is it possible to connect to these PPTP sessions via the terminal if I only have SSH access, using these predefined sessions, so I don't have to type all the details in again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out this is a duplicate of another question which I couldn't previously find;

[Connect/disconnect from VPN from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57339/connect-disconnect-from-vpn-from-the-command-line)

I would like to add though, to install nmcli on my 10.04 machine I had to;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:network-manager/trunk  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Comment: nmcli is now available without a ppa **15.10**

Comment: nmcli uses clear text passwords (if you are accessing from CLI) and is not secure.

Answer (score 2):

try to configure *pppd*, [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-configure-pptp-vpn-in-ubuntu-intrepid-and-jaunty.html) is an example. i believe you understand that your configuration file can differ.

Answer (score 0):

use the 'pppd' to accomplish it:

> sudo pppd nodetach defaultroute replacedefaultroute persist password
>   mypassword file myvpn

replace "mypassword" with your pptp account's password.
the "myvpn" is a config file, format as:

```
linkname myvpn 
ipparam myvpn 
pty "pptp server_address --nolaunchpppd " 
name myaccount 
usepeerdns 
require-mppe 
refuse-eap noauth

# adopt defaults from the pptp-linux package 
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
```

this config file format is mentioned in here:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient

And, "nodetach", or "defaultroute" are options for pppd, been described here:http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/pppd.8.html

I have use this method in java to setup a pptp client vpn connection, yes, it works.

The pid file, is in /var/run/ppp-xxx.pid, the "xxx" is your linkname that in your config file. You can read the pid of pppd from this pid file send a signal to the pppd, e.g "sudo kill -s SIGTERM pid_of_pppd", to shutdown the pppd.