# How to create a tunneling connection for remote screen sharing

Tags: remote-desktop, tunnel

I have the following setup:

My Computer --> ISP Router --> Internet --> Company ISP Router --> Company Router --> Switch --> Company Server.

Using Teamviewer I can share the Company Server with My Computer in 2 or 3 steps. That is, install Teamviewer on both computers and simply input the ID and password of the Server in My Computer. Done.

I wish to stop using Teamviewer for several reasons and start using other VNC like options. The one I want to try is Remmina. Does Remmina have the capability to remotely connect from My Computer to the Company Server and if so how?

What are the steps needed to actual remotely connect (including tunneling my way) to the Server, in the same fashion and ease of use as Teamviewer. It might not be easy the first time because I would guess I would need to configure a couple of things first on both sides but the ideal situation is one where I could simply open Remmina on the client side and connect directly to the server.

If the Remmina tool is not able to accomplish this, what other open source tools are available (Avoiding ones like Teamviewer from the list).

There are a couple of things I would like to avoid (if possible):

- Not modifying the Router or any in the middle hardware. Just the Client and Server PCs.
- Not compiling anything that changes the Ubuntu system. Installing a package from apt / synaptic / software center should be enough.

Comment: Is opening a [reverse ssh tunnel](http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling) not an option? If so you just need to open a defined port on your side and direct that to a ssh server running on your side...

Comment: "Not modifying the Router or any in the middle hardware", does that include your own router or just the company where you work one?

Comment: Good questions Bruno, the modifying question only includes stuff in the company, not my own router. I can modify mine if there is some steps that needs this. For the reverse ssh that is a plus but for the moment I need VNC like (Similar to Teamviewer). Still reading through the Remmina guide to see if there is an option for this kind of need. Thanks for the questions.

Comment: Would something like SSH tunnel of x11vnc work for you? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/245850/how-to-connect-to-home-computer-from-work-computer-behind-vpn-using-remote-desk