# Can't connect to the internet and touchpad frozen after update to 20.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, touchpad

Updated 20.04 this morning, and now the touchpad is frozen and I can't connect to the internet.

nmcli d gives:

```
DEVICE     TYPE     STATE        CONNECTION
virbr0     bridge   disconnected --
lo         loopback unmanaged    --
vurbr0-nic tun      unmanaged    --
```

Am hoping that if I can get connected to the internet I can try to update again, in order to resolve the touchpad issue, but not sure how to start trying to fix this or even what information would be useful in terms of getting some advice.

Any help much appreciated.

Edits follow:

Hardware: Lenovo Legion 5

Ubuntu: 20.04 desktop

I can't see all the results from sudo lshw -C network because the terminal window is quite small, and I can't resize because the touchpad is frozen. But I can see:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet controller
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
version: 15
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory c220400-c2204fff memory:c2200000-c2203fff
*-network DISABLED
description ethernet interface
physical id: 3
logical name: virbr0-nic
serial: 52:54:00:95:c7:f9
size: 10Mbit/s
capabilities: ethernet physical
configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces gives "No such file or directory"

And cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml gives:

```
#Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Is this a VM? Turn off VPN. Check your bridge settings.

Comment: Hi heynnema -- thanks for the reply. Way out of my depth here. Take it you mean a virtual machine. Don't think it's a virtual machine, or certainly not on purpose. Not sure how to turn off VPN. This page https://askubuntu.com/questions/57339/connect-disconnect-from-vpn-from-the-command-line suggests you can turn named connections off and on with nmcli con up or nmcli con down. But when I try nmcli con, all I get is a list of saved connections with type "wifi" and device "--". If I try `nmcli con up id` with the id of my wifi network, I get an error "No suitable device found". Any thoughts?

Comment: What hardware? What version Ubuntu? Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Thanks -- can't see some of the results for `sudo lshw -C network` but have added all I can. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: You need to figure out how to disable your VPN during testing.

Your /etc/netplan/*.yaml file is incorrect. Change it to look like this... keep indentation and spacing the same...

change:

```
#Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
version: 2
renderer: Network Manager
```

to this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

Time to backup important files and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for this. The *.yaml file was already in the form you suggested -- I mistyped the extra space in NetworkManager, and couldn't work out how to format the indents in the comment. Have tried generating, applying and rebooting, but no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: In settings/network it's showing VPN as "Not set up", with Network Proxy "Off"

Comment: @erk Time to backup important files and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Ach -- terrible news. Any other possibilities?

Comment: @erk Assuming that this was working before the upgrade, something went wrong during/after the upgrade. We could spend hours trying to figure out what's wrong with the system, or spend 20 minutes reinstalling. You could try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if it works that way.

Comment: @erk Status please...